# Lateral scrolling in and scrolling out using scrolltop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have an image which i want to smoothly scorllin when user scrolls down and scrolls up the image should go back to original positon.
to do this i thought of using

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

as

```
$(".slogan").css('margin-left', -$(window).scrollTop());
```

but i am not able to see a difference. i tried to use stellar.js for this but dont know how to do it with stellar.

any help will be appreciated

thanks
Masood Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `$(document)` not `$(window)`

Instead of margins, I would set the image's `position` property to `position: fixed`

It seems you want the image to scroll to the right while the use scrolls down so here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJ9YJ/1/) using the jquery below

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    $(".scrolling").css("left", $(document).scrollTop());
});
```